# For loop creating lists to append to other list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently programming something in Python.

I converted some csv files into lists and now i wanted to put thoose lists in to a PostgresSQL. But my problem is i have to filter the lists becuase some lists contain values from more DB tables. So i wrote some functions to split them up:

My List looks like this:

```
[['AUS', 'Australia', 'Sydney', '2000', '2000-09-15', '2000-10-01'], ['AUS|SWE', 'Australia|Sweden', 'Melbourne|Stockholm', '1956', '1956-06-10', '1956-12-08']]
```

I need to extract the year, start date and end date in my example the indexes 3, 4 and 5.

So i pass the list to my function

```
def gam_list(g_lst):
  return_list = []
  part_list = []
  for item in g_lst:
    part_list.append(item[3])
    part_list.append(item[4])
    part_list.append(item[5])
  return_list.append(part_list)
  print(part_list)
  return return_list
```

But when i print the list i get something like this

```
['2000', '2000-09-15', '2000-10-01', '1956', '1956-06-10', '1956-12-08']
```

But i need the output i this Format

```
[['2000', '2000-09-15', '2000-10-01'], ['1956', '1956-06-10', '1956-12-08']]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can just do `[item[3:6] for item in g_lst]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use this snippet. I made some improvements to your code.

```
a = [['AUS', 'Australia', 'Sydney', '2000', '2000-09-15', '2000-10-01'], ['AUS|SWE', 'Australia|Sweden', 'Melbourne|Stockholm', '1956', '1956-06-10', '1956-12-08']]

def gam_list(g_lst):
  return_list = []
  for item in g_lst:
    return_list.append(item[3:6])
  print(return_list)
  return return_list

gam_list(a)
```

You're gonna see this output as you want:

`[['2000', '2000-09-15', '2000-10-01'], ['1956', '1956-06-10', '1956-12-08']]`

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new list each time in the iteration, and add that list to the results.

```
def gam_list(g_lst):
  return_list = []
  for item in g_lst:
    part_list = [] # Moved this here
    part_list.append(item[3])
    part_list.append(item[4])
    part_list.append(item[5])
    return_list.append(part_list) # Added this
  print(return_list) # Changed this
  return return_list
```